# Get number of duplicates from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

For example, say I have an `ArrayList` that could contain the following values:

```
x
x
x
y
y
```

Now what I want to retrieve is the number of `x` and `x` and I want to be able to differentiate what I have, either `x` or `y` because in actuality, I could have any object in the ArrayList and I have to be able to tell them apart.

What I was thinking  of doing was first converting the `ArrayList` into a `LinkedHashSet`, which would keep the ordering and remove the duplicates so I would just have `x` and `y` But how would I get the number of each and associate it with the proper element?

Overall what I want to do is to be able to write a `toString` method that will let me output:

```
x3y2
```

But without knowing that `x` and `y` are the elements because they could have been something else like `z` or `w`.

Comment: Are each instance of an object equal to each other?  So is x == x and y == y? or are just the types equal Integer == Integer and String == String, but they could have different values?

Comment: Is the `ArrayList` allowed to be modified?

Comment: @Wizetux The instances are equal to each other.

Comment: @hmjd I would prefer not, but if there's not another way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the Multiset in google guava: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

Example:

```
Multiset<String> strings = HashMultiset.create(arrayList);
int countX = strings.count("x"); // the count of x
```

More examples can be found on the [Guava wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use a `HashMap<Object, Long>`.  Store the Object as the key and the Long as the occurrence count.

Here's some pseudo code which will do what you're trying to do.

```
for(x in list) {
 if(x in Map) {
   map.put(x, map.get(x)++);
 } else {
   map.put(x, 1);
 }
}
```

You can then iterate through the Map and print the value and occurrence count.  I'll let you write that one up.  It's easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this what you can do is to traverse the `list` from the end. Keep a counter and keep checking for the change in the object. As soon as you detect a change, replace the number in the counter with the `current position + 1`. Do this till you reach the first position.